# Subscription in Tracker.autorun causes publish callback to fire multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm working in a ReactJS and Meteor project and I found a strange behavior I'm gonna describe here:

There is a `Tracker.autorun` block with a `Meteor.subscribe` call inside. So far, so good. In the server side, there is a matching `Meteor.publish` which declares a callback.

As far as I understand, the `Meteor.publish` callback should fire once for each subscription received, but somehow this callback is firing 3~4 times for a single subscription.

In my last test the `Tracker.autorun` block executed 4 times, the subscribe only executed 1 single time and the callback fired 4 times.

The `Meteor.subscribe` only runs once, even the tracker runs several times. How could it cause the callback to fire more the once?

Does it make sense?
Do you know what could explain such behavior?

If you need any other information, just let me know.
Thanks in advance

```
Meteor.publish('current-user', function currentUser(credentials) {
  return Users.find();
});
```

```
Tracker.autorun((c) => {
  if (!currentUserHandler) {
    currentUserHandler = Meteor.subscribe('current-user', this.credentials);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this the full code? Is `this.credentials` a reactive data source like `ReactiveVar` or `ReactiveDict`?

Comment: No, it's not the full code actually. `this.credentials` is a object that holds some values from session storage.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect that the autorun will fire twice as a normal condition, once without data, and the second with some data.

That is to allow you to show a "loading" state before the data arrives.

You are subscribing to the `users` collection, which is a `special` collection. Meteor uses it for authentication, and also to record session activity. You are doing a `Users.find()`, which is an unfiltered query on the whole users collection, so any modification to any user will cause it to fire. You also won't be able to see all of the users records (for security reasons).

It's probable that you are storing additional data on the users record, hence the need for you to subscribe to it. I would recommend that you consider storing this data in another collection, such as 'members', 'visitors', 'profiles' or whatever name suits you. Things are likely to work better that way.

Comment: The `Users.find` has a selector, but I omitted in the example code, my bad. What I don't understand is why only one subscribe causes the callback to fire multiple times.

Comment: It's being called for a reason, either the user collection is being modified, or the credentials object contains a reactive variable. Remember that Meteor looks at anything you use in this autorun method and makes it reactive for you.

Comment: So, each time the `Tracker.autorun` reruns, if there is a `Meteor.subscbribe` inside of it, it is expected that the matching `Meteor.publish` callback will rerun even if the `subscribe` call doesn't re-execute?